# Using SSL/TLS prtocols to secure communication with m2mqtt

Tags: c#, ssl, mqtt

I am developing an MQTT Client that publishes data into MQTT Brokers. My application is right now able to publish plain text data, I need to encrypt these data using TLS protocol. This option is provided by the m2mqtt.dll but I have a few questions.

**Question 1:**
What type of certificate should I generate?

**Question 2:**
If I am running two MQTT Clients that publish into two different brokers(iot.eclipse.org and broker.hivemq.com), should I generate two different certificates for both MQTT Clients?

**Question 3:**
Should I assign the same certificate to both MQTT Client publisher and MQTT Client subscriber that will consume published data ?

Comment: You should not need to create any certificates to connect to those 2 brokers, you just need to have access to suitable CA certificate chains to validate the certificates those brokers already have.

Comment: How could I access to suitable CA certificate chains of these brokers ?

Comment: Both brokers use certificates signed by public Certificate Authorities their certificates should be included in nearly all available operating systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to create client certificates if you want to use the certificate to identify the client.

The 2 public brokers you have mentioned in the question are very unlikely to accept any client certificates for authentication (also you should not be using them for anything other than very basic proof of concept as they totally open to the public and only offered for educational use).

If you are running your own broker configured with SSL/TLS then you will know which CA you need to have sign any certificates you may wish to issue to clients.

1. Standard x509 certificates
2. See comments on the question and the notes above
3. This entirely depends on what you are trying to archive, if you care about being able to tell your clients apart (maybe for ACL purposes) then you will want different certificates. If you only care that clients are from a known source then you could reuse certificates.